# When binding an ObservableCollection<T> to a ListView, how does the ListView go about retrieving the data to display?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was browsing around Microsoft's site, and got caught up reading [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

I came up with a quick scenario in my head, and determined I could actually use something like this.

I made a sample class that inherets from ObservableCollection<T>, as seen here:

```
public class Ledger : ObservableCollection<LedgerEntry>, IEnumerable
{
    private ObservableCollection<LedgerEntry> _items;
    private decimal _currentBalance;

    public Ledger(IEnumerable<LedgerEntry> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<LedgerEntry>(items);
        _currentBalance = 0m;
    }

    public new IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        var enumerator = _items.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var currentItem = enumerator.Current;

            _currentBalance += currentItem.Amount;
            currentItem.SetBalance(_currentBalance);

            yield return currentItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Think about a bank account -- I'd like for each LedgerEntry contained within the collection to "know" it's balance.

Any who --

What I'm wondering is this -- given the above example, I see that GetEnumerator() is called once when I bind it to a ListView, and now I'm curious -- how is ListView actually retrieving / viewing the data contained within the collection?

My thought was that it would iterate the enumerable, but apparently I'm incorrect.

Any info on how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the collection implements `IList<T>` that will be used to access the items by index instead.

Comment: Something that is odd is that the GetEnumerator method is called once if I directly implement IEnumerable, but it is not called at all if I take ", IEnumerable" off of the class signature.